# How to debug PHP pages accessed through PHP cURL using Netbeans and XDebug

Tags: php, netbeans, curl, xdebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using XDebug to trace a PHP web service page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045316/using-xdebug-to-trace-a-php-web-service-page)

My Problem is XDebug or Netbeans would not break on the page that is
being accessed using cURL. I have used xdebug_break(); and created a break point on the page accessed by cURL but it still does not break there.

Hope somebody here could help, I have looked around the web but could
not find any solution to it.

Here is my Setup:

- NetBeans IDE, the PHP page accessed through cURL and WAMP Server
  are on the same computer. So everything is located on my local computer
- I am using PHP 5.3.8, Apache 2.2.21, Wamp Server 2.2, NetBeans 7.0.1
- xDebug is working but the only problem i have is when I use cURL to a php page where I
  have set a break point but it will not break there

Inside php.ini

```
[dba]
;dba.default_handler=
; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:

; XDEBUG Extension
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=Off
;xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```