# PHP Web service development using Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, service, web, xdebug

I have a simple web service(Restful) developed using PHP, it is purely service, no web page at all. Previously I simply used Aptana as text editor, and put all the source files under the WAMP server's www directory. Now there are more features needed so I would like to use Netbeans as the IDE and utilize the XDebug to do debugging(previously I simply used logs to find errors). However I can not find a suitable tutorial to get started. I have imported the php files into the Netbeans 7.4 as a PHP application, but I got lost how to configure it so it can "run" on the WAMP server and doing debug. Can anyone either show me how to do the basic configuration or point out some good tutorials?

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link provided in your comments, now it works, here is the config in the php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "d:/wamp/tmp"
```

this line must be included: "xdebug.remote_autostart=on", previously I did not have it, nor the xdebug.idekey, however the  xdebug.idekey is not important, it can be different than the session id in the Options.

Answer (score 0):

What did you research? Let me google that for you: `php netbeans xdebug`

2nd result is [Debugging PHP Source Code in the NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html)

During that tutorial, it links to a [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html) of how to set up XAMPP (not WAMP) for NetBeans.

Comment: I have read that article a while back. When using the PHPInfo, the XDebug is already enabled. I modified the the php.ini to use the port 9000, and in the Netbeans Options also set the port to be 9000. However when I clicked the Debug, there is a message on the bottom right "Waiting to connect ..." and it just stays there. As I said this is a web service, so technically it does not really run until some requests being sent from a client. I am not quite sure how to connect to XDebug and when a request comes in the breakpoint get triggered. If you can provide specifics I would appreciate that.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the service handler. Follow advice here to generate a client request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045316/using-xdebug-to-trace-a-php-web-service-page

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989222/attaching-netbeans-to-xdebug-on-xampp-webservice-fails